# Cartesian Product on unknown number of php arrays

Tags: php, cartesian-product

I need to get every unique combination from a number of separate arrays. I do not know how many arrays, as this may vary.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think I should be using the `Cartesian Product` method.

---

**This is a basic outline of what my data will be.**

```
[
    {
        "department": "CIS",
        "name": "Intro to CIS",
        "sections": {
            "01": {
                "regNum": "012345",
                "days": "MWF",
                "startTime": "900",
                "endTime": "1030",
                "labDay": "M",
                "labStartTime": "1300",
                "labEndTime": "1500"
            },
            "02": {
                "regNum": "098304",
                "days": "TR",
                "startTime": "1300",
                "endTime": "1500",
                "labDay": "",
                "labStartTime": "",
                "labEndTime": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "department": "MATH",
        "name": "Intro to MATH",
        "sections": {
            "01": {
                "regNum": "012345",
                "days": "MWF",
                "startTime": "900",
                "endTime": "1030",
                "labDay": "M",
                "labStartTime": "1300",
                "labEndTime": "1500"
            },
            "02": {
                "regNum": "098304",
                "days": "TR",
                "startTime": "1300",
                "endTime": "1500",
                "labDay": "",
                "labStartTime": "",
                "labEndTime": ""
            }
        }
    }
]
```

---

**Desired result:**

```
[[[CIS 01 Array],[MATH 01 Array]],
 [[CIS 01 Array],[MATH 02 Array]],
 [[CIS 02 Array],[MATH 01 Array]],
 [[CIS 02 Array],[MATH 02 Array]]
]
```

Note that these are arrays since I still need to be able to access days, startTime ..etc

Comment: I have been thinking through it for a while now and do not know how to implement this.

Comment: You need to use nested loops.

Comment: You could also use recursion. Write the code for getting the cross product of just 2 arrays. If you have more than 2 arrays, get the cross product of the first 2 arrays, then recurse with that result and the remaining arrays.

Comment: @Barmar please see my edit

Comment: @Barmar I believe that would work for my example but my actual data structure is a bit different since I am using JSON

Comment: Once you call `json_decode()`, it's just arrays. The fact that it came from JSON is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I know. Please see my data structure above

Comment: Don't post images, post plain text. Use the `{}` tool to mark it as code to keep the formatting.

Comment: What result are you trying to get from that? I don't see anything that should be combined into a cross product.

Comment: I want each course to be added into a new array with the iteration of all other courses.

For instance it should go [[CIS 01,MATH 01],[CIS 01, MATH 02]..etc]

Comment: Show the full desired result in the question. It's basically the same algorithm in my answer, except instead of concatenating strings, you use `array_merge()` to combine arrays.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated it

Comment: What does `CIS 01 Array` mean? Is that supposed to be a character string that concatenates the department and the section number? What does `Array` represent?

Comment: That's not really a cartesian product. You've simply replaced each department with an array of all its sections, and then concatenated them all.

Comment: @Barmar It literally means the object of the courses section that contains regNum, days, startTime ..etc. I said array because I am guessing that it got converted over to an associative array on json_decode

Comment: @Barmar So in the end I am wanting an array that holds arrays containing associative arrays that were once the section objects

Comment: Is `[CIS 01 Array]` supposed to be `['CIS', '01', <associative array>]` or `['CIS 01' => <associative array>]`?

Comment: @Barmar Essentially I want each "associative array" to take the form of `["dept" => "CIS", "section" => "01", "regNum" => "012345", "days" => "MWF" ..etc]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing a cartesian product of all the departments, just a product of each department and its sections. You just need 2 nested loops, one for the departments and another for the sections within the department.  You can then add the department name and section number to the associative array, and push it onto the result.

```
$departments = json_decode($json_string, true);
$result = array();
foreach ($departments as $dept) {
    $name = $dept['department'];
    foreach ($dept['sections'] as $sectno => $secdata) {
        $secdata['dept'] = $name;
        $secdata['section'] = $sectno;
        $result[] = $secdata;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/hLpZdH)

Comment: I am getting an error at `foreach ($dept['sections'] as $sectno => $secdata) `

Comment: You going to keep me guessing what the error is? How about replacing the image of the JSON with plain text, so I can paste it into my code and test?

Comment: Ok, will do. It is just a parse error. I think it has to do with assigning the associative identifier

Comment: hmm worked that time. Thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry to bug you once again, but the output isn't quite right. It currently prints out all of the possible sections but what I need is the following:

`[[0] => [[CIS 01 Data],[MATH 01 DATA]], [1] => [[CIS 01 Data],[MATH 02 DATA]], [2] => [[CIS 02 Data],[MATH 01 DATA]], [3] => [[CIS 02 Data],[MATH 02 DATA]]]`

In pseudocode of course

Comment: That's not what you said in the question.

Comment: I mentioned it in the comment thread we had. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: That was before you updated the question to show what you wanted the result to look like.

Comment: I explained how to do it with recursion. Maybe instead of expecting me to do all your work for you, you could try to implement that yourself.

Comment: So far you've shown absolutely no attempt to solve this on your own. What kind of programmer are you?

Comment: Frankly I would not have come to SO to solve my own problems. I did not know how to go about this so I came here to seek some help

Comment: I think I've provide quite a bit of help. I've given you code that merges the department name and section into the associative array, and I explained in a comment how you can do the cartesian products with a recursive function.

Comment: I am passing the 4 arrays created into the cartesian_product() function. It returns NULL

Comment: That is after running what we previously had

Comment: I have been trying but I cannot get it to work in conjunction with cartesian_product(). I would appreciate if you could help me out just once more. Then I will be on my way.

Comment: If you've been trying, it means you have some code you wrote that doesn't work. Put it in the question. I'm not going to do it from scratch for you.